# Ionic 3 same Menu into Pages

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, menu, ionic2, ionic3

i'm new here !

I build app in Ionic 3, and I have a problem with my menu, I have two pages and when I change page, my Menu is not the same :

That is my menu in the main page :

http://hpics.li/74165a3

And that is my menu when I change to another :

[Menu When i Change page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XodbB.png)

Code :

```
  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the nav controller to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.rootPage = page;

    // close the menu when clicking a link from the menu
    this.menu.close();
}
```

Can someone help me ?

Thanks !

**EDIT :**

This is my app.component.ts :

```
    import {Component, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
import {Events, MenuController, NavController, Platform, Nav} from "ionic-angular";
import {ControlPanelComponent} from "../pages/controlpanel/controlpanel";
import {TicketJourPage} from "../pages/ticket-jour/ticket-jour";
import {SplashScreen} from "@ionic-native/splash-screen";
import {PronosServiceProvider} from '../providers/pronos-service/pronos-service';
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html',
    providers:  [PronosServiceProvider],
})
export class MyApp {
    @ViewChild(Nav) navCtrl;
    public homePage = ControlPanelComponent;
    public settingsPage = ControlPanelComponent;
    public ticketdujour = TicketJourPage;
    public splash = new SplashScreen();
    public rootPage: any;
    public nameUser : string;


    constructor(public platform: Platform,
                public menu: MenuController,
                public events: Events,) {
        console.log("In MyApp constructor");
            console.log("Hiding splash screen");
            this.splash.hide();
    }
    openPage(page) {
        //this.rootPage = page;
        console.log("OPENPAGE")
        this.navCtrl.setroot(page.component);

        // close the menu when clicking a link from the menu
        this.menu.close();
    }

}
```

And this is my app.html :

```
<ion-menu id="loggedInMenu" [content]="content" style="background-color: transparent;"  persistent="true">
    <ion-content style="background: url('img/background.jpg'); background-size: cover;">
        <ion-list style="background-color: transparent;" no-lines>
            <ion-item style="background-color: transparent; margin-top: 10px;" class="logo" align="left">
              <p class="font3" style="color: white; font-size: 1rem; margin-left: -80px">{{ vari.Username }}</p><br>
              <p [hidden]="vari.bool" class="font3" style="color: #ffae00; font-size: 1rem;" align="left">Premium - </p><p class="test" style="color: white; font-size: 1rem;">{{ vari.date }}</p>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>

        <ion-list style="background-color: transparent;">
            <button ion-item (click)="openPage(ticketdujour)"  style="background-color: transparent;" >

                <p class="font3" style="color: white; font-size: 1.1rem;">Ticket du Jour</p>
            </button>
            <button ion-item (click)="openPage(homePage)"  style="background-color: transparent;">

                <p class="font3" style="color: white; font-size: 1.1rem;">Pronostiques</p>
            </button>
            <button ion-item (click)="openPage(pronopage)"  style="background-color: transparent;">

                <p class="font3" style="color: white; font-size: 1.1rem;">Gestion de Bankroll</p>
            </button>
            <button ion-item (click)="openPage(homePage)"  style="background-color: transparent;">

                <p class="font3" style="color: white; font-size: 1.1rem;">Aide à l'analyse</p>
            </button>
            <button ion-item (click)="openPage(homePage)"  style="background-color: transparent;">

                <p class="font3" style="color: white; font-size: 1.1rem;">Premium</p>
            </button>
            <button ion-item (click)="openPage(homePage)"  style="background-color: transparent;">

                <p class="font3" style="color: white; font-size: 1.1rem;">Profil</p>
            </button>
            <button ion-item (click)="openPage(logoutPage)"  style="background-color: transparent;">
                <p class="font3" style="color: white; font-size: 1.1rem;">Déconnexion</p>
            </button>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav id="nav" #content [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

PS : vari.Username for exmaple is Global Varibales.

Comment: Try to be more specific about what you want in your answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm Sorry, I want know why my Menu changed when I change page in my App (see photos)

Answer (score 0):

In a default sidemenu template, in app.component.ts, the **openPage(page)** function will look like this,

```
openPage(page){ this.nav.setroot(page.component); }
```

Note that, page.component is a string "HomePage" if you used Lazy Loading.
   Here this.nav refers to **Nav** from **ionic-angular**, and the menuclose attribute comes by default in app.html file. This works perfectly without any errors as you said, So I suggest you to follow the default template code, which is meant to guide you how to code for IONIC APP !!

If you still face any issue please share your html code.

Comment: Thanks for answer ! But this not work, I have "this.navCtrl.setroot is not a function"... I have Edit my post with my app.html and app.component.ts

Comment: In App.component.ts, It is suggested not to use NavController, U may try Nav instead of NavController

Answer (score 0):

This is function check what page you open, depends on you can ruling side menu as you like.

```
`appCtrl.viewWillEnter.subscribe(
   (view) => {
    //  here you can check page and do as you want
  }`
```